# Android&XML: inset xmlns変更にアクセス拒否

Tags: android, xml

現在の質問は[Android: 入力フィールドとボタンの幅をぴったり合わせる](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/29662/android-%E5%85%A5%E5%8A%9B%E3%83%95%E3%82%A3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%83%89%E3%81%A8%E3%83%9C%E3%82%BF%E3%83%B3%E3%81%AE%E5%B9%85%E3%82%92%E3%81%B4%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8A%E5%90%88%E3%82%8F%E3%81%9B%E3%82%8B?noredirect=1#comment28659_29662)という課題の続きです。その質問に入力フィールドとボタンの幅を合わせるには、次の解決策が提供されました：

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:insetBottom="@android:dimen/button_inset_vertical_material"
    android:insetLeft="@android:dimen/button_inset_horizontal_material"
    android:insetRight="@android:dimen/button_inset_horizontal_material"
    android:insetTop="@android:dimen/button_inset_vertical_material">

    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#ffcccc" />
        <corners android:radius="2dip" />
        <padding
            android:bottom="0dip"
            android:left="0dip"
            android:right="0dip"
            android:top="0dip" />
    </shape>
</inset>
```

残念ながら、出たエラーメッセージによると、`<inset xmlns>`を再定義する事が許可されていないようです：

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ですけど、前の質問に親切に答えたlitmonさんのパソコンにはこのエラーがなかったようです。
もしかして、原因はアクセス変更子に関係ないか、更新したAndroid SDKにはアクセスできなくなったかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

システムリソース（`@android:` から始まるもの）や、ライブラリのリソースには、参照することのできない `private` リソースが存在します。

ここで出ているエラーメッセージは、Inset Drawable を定義していることが問題なのではなく、

- `@android:dimen/button_inset_vertical_material`
- `@android:dimen/button_inset_horizontal_material`

この二つのシステムリソースが `private` リソースのためです。

本来、こうした値は予告なく変更されたり削除される可能性があるため、推奨はしないのですが、

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:insetBottom="@*android:dimen/button_inset_vertical_material"
    android:insetLeft="@*android:dimen/button_inset_horizontal_material"
    android:insetRight="@*android:dimen/button_inset_horizontal_material"
    android:insetTop="@*android:dimen/button_inset_vertical_material">

    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#ffcccc" />
        <corners android:radius="2dip" />
        <padding
        android:bottom="0dip"
        android:left="0dip"
        android:right="0dip"
        android:top="0dip" />
    </shape>
</inset>
```

リソース参照の先頭を `@*` に変更することで、参照することは可能です。

最善の方法は、システムリソースから必要な部分のみ、自分のプロジェクトにコピーして使うことです。

Comment: ご解答、誠にありがとうございます。お手数ですが、最善の解決の例を見せて頂いても宜しいでしょうか。

Comment: @GurebuBokofu `button_inset_vertical_material` と `button_inset_horizontal_material` の定義を参照すれば、それぞれ 6dp と 4dp の値だと分かるので、それを自分のプロジェクトの `dimen.xml` 内に定義するなり、または `android:insetBottom` などの値を直接置き換えるだけです。そうすれば、将来的にシステムリソースの値が変更したり削除されても影響を受けません。より万全を期すなら、`Button` や `EditText` に設定されているデフォルトの背景画像ごと持ってくるという感じですね。

Comment: 背景画像ごと持ってくるのは一番簡単だったという事が分かりました^^改めて感謝します。